# Multiple date fields

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a customized [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) view. When I created the view using the template, it allowed me to select one field to be used as the date.
Is it possible to have multiple date fields, for example *Due date*, *Start date*, and *Review Date*? The node should show on the calendar for each date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this adding or statements to my calendar's existing contextual filter. I added each date field as an "or" statement and now it shows each date on the calendar.